# Font Stretching with different monitor screen resolution

Tags: wpf, fonts

```
<Grid Name="maingrid">
    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Height="Auto">
    <dp:DockablePanel x:Name="dockPanel" Width="980" Height="710"  Margin="0,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <dp:DockablePanel.DockPanelCollection>
            <dp:ChildPanel StripTitle="" Dock="Left" ParentName="Window1" Eve_MenuItemClicked="menuAssets_GotMouseCapture"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
                <dp:ChildPanel.OpacityMask>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.131,0.161" StartPoint="0.143,0.163">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </dp:ChildPanel.OpacityMask>
                <dp:ChildPanel.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="6" Color="#FF000000" Direction="-60" Opacity="0.68" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                </dp:ChildPanel.Effect>
            </dp:ChildPanel>
</dp:DockablePanel.DockPanelCollection>
        <dp:DockablePanel.CenterContent>
            <TextBlock></TextBlock>
        </dp:DockablePanel.CenterContent>
    </dp:DockablePanel>
        </Viewbox>
```

where works ok on my system where  my screen resolution is 1024 and 768,but the font (menu panel font ) gets stretched on running this exe on another system (with monitor screen resolution (1280 ,768) or (1366,768) ,please provide me a solution regarding this

Answer (score 2):

When you expect your application to properly run in full-screen mode, you need to think about a real layout.

If your application has to run on systems with different aspect ratios like 4:3 (1024x768), 5:3 (1280x768) and 16:9 (1366x768), you can not simply put everything in a `ViewBox` and expect it to fill the entire screen and at the same time keep the aspect ratio.

Either you incorporate a layout that allows for different aspect ratios, or you simply don't fill the screen. Consider dropping your top-level `ViewBox` and read about the layout options offered by e.g. `Grid`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Height="Auto">
```

Comment: the stretch issue is cleared now,but the alignment left side margin been changed now (after using stretch="uniform")

Comment: @karthik2004k, that's the trade-off.  If you don't want that to happen, don't use a Viewbox.